# Website not opening properly on any browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-8.1, browser, internet-explorer

I have been using this [Website](http://www.scopus.com) (Scopus research database) for years, without a problem. I simply go to Scopus.com, click on "Other Institution Login", choose my institution from the list, and follow the screens to login.

However, recently (about 1 month ago), something happened (maybe Windows update, I suspect) that has resulted in Scopus not opening properly on any of my browsers (Firefox 64, IE, Chrome). What happens now is: once I click on "Other Institution Login", the second screen won't have any useful clickable buttons and looks like the screenshot below. If you click "help page" at the top red ribbon to see why the page was not loading correctly, it doesn't give much help to resolve the problem. However, if I leave my PC and I browse using my iPad, it works just fine. So, the problem is confined to my PC.

Any suggestions to solve this?

I use Windows 8.1 (`winver` gives: Win 8 version 6.3, build 9600), 64-bits

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While it is *possible* a windows update broke it, it is *HIGHLY* improbable.  More than likely it is your virus protection, or some other 3rd party application.  IF you have backups or system restore points past where the issue started, you can restore the machine to an earlier state to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. Which component/settings of the AntiVirus would be responsible? And why would it suddenly happen even though I haven't changed AntiVirus settings for a long time (2 years)? I use Kaspersky Total Security. Any suggestions?